# Symfony 2 minify dynamic javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have to build a webservice in order to send a webpage to some others websites.
Theses websites will integrate this webpage inside another one.

I have to send the assets separetely from the webpage. 
For performances issues, I musn't use AJAX requests.

One of my javascript files, need businness data in order to display and validate form fields according to complex business rules (Administration).

So far I'm using a "js.twig" template, so I can easily add my data to my script.

However, I'm asked to minify this file (performance and intellectual property). 
How can I minify my file "on the fly" ?

Update :

I'm not asking for a tool. I already have one. I need leads about calling a "minifyier on the fly". Filo gave a pretty good on the subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close under the "recommend or find a tool" reason, because the answer to this question is to find a server-side minifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably this answer can help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947488/3625883

If you want a library in pure php to perform the compression, you can use https://code.google.com/p/minify/

**For installation:**
add in composer.json

```
 "mrclay/minify": "2.2.0"
```

Then you can use Assetic filter: jsminplus (https://github.com/jbroadway/assetic/blob/master/lib/JSMinPlus.php )